# Unable to resolve module tensorflow_inception_graph.pb as a file nor as a folder

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

Here I am using [tensor flow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) with react native using [react-native-tensorflow](https://github.com/reneweb/react-native-tensorflow) llibrary. The library has installed properly. The code snippet which I am using and facing an issue is

```
const tfImageRecognition = new TfImageRecognition({
model: require('./assets/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb'),
labels: require('./assets/tensorflow_labels.txt'),
imageMean: 117, // Optional, defaults to 117
imageStd: 1 // Optional, defaults to 1 })
```

In the model property, when I am loading the `tensorflow_inception_graph.pb` file then it is giving me the error

```
    error: bundling failed: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module 
    `../asset/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb` from 
        `/Users/XYZ/App/code/Demo/src/ImageRecognitionAI.js`:
 could not resolve `/Users/XYZ/App/code/Demo/src/assets/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb'
        as a file nor as a folder
```

The file path which I am passing in model is checked and found correct. Can anyone help me to get out of this? Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

place the tenserflow_labels.text and tensorflow_inception_graph.pb and  file in the assets folder

=> android/app/src/main/assets/tensorflow_inception_graph.pb

=> android/app/src/main/assets/tenserflow_labels.text

now you can access it like this in your js file.

```
const tf = new TfImageRecognition({
        model: 'file://tensorflow_inception_graph.pb',
        labels: 'file://tenserflow_labels.txt'
      });
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the webpack type extensions in either the package or a `rn-cli.config.js` file.  If you're using `create-react-native-app` then you want to add it to the `app.json` file like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "27.0.0",
    "packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": ["pb", "txt"]
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't find that in the documentation for some reason, but I found it in some example [projects](https://github.com/expo/elements-example-crna/blob/master/app.json#L4-L6).

If you're running your scripts with `react-native start` then you need to setup a `rn-cli.config.js` file. Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/reneweb/react-native-tensorflow#fetching-files)

```
module.exports = {
  getAssetExts() {
    return ['pb', 'txt']
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working. I create rn-cli.config.js file, as described in documentation, but nothing changing.

Comment: @JhonatanPereira , tried both the options. its not working :(

Comment: @Arjun I do that: `const text = {uri: 'asset:/a.txt'};
const graph = {uri: 'asset:/graph.pb'};
const tfImageRecognition = new TfImageRecognition({
        model: graph,
        labels: text
      });`

And it's ok now. Otherside, I get another error on this part:
`const results = await tfImageRecognition.recognize({
        image: require('./assets/yodawhitehouse.jpg')
      });`
Error: could not load resource.

Comment: Put txt and pb files on `android/app/src/main/assets` folder. Some help in 'required' error mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running scripts from **rn-cli.config.js**

change file content to :

```
    const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();

  return {
    resolver: {
      assetExts: [...assetExts, "pb", "txt"]
    }
  };
})();
```